# Converting UTC Datetime to local Datetime result in Error

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin

Below is the line of code that is causing issue. I need to convert current UTC time to local time as per local time zone.

Note: Not using DateTime.Now because DateTime.Now provided cached value even after clearing the TimeZone cache when system time has been modified.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local)
```

```
System.ArgumentException: Kind property of dateTime is Utc but the sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc

ERROR at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc (System.DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, System.TimeZoneInfoOptions flags) <0x104615320 + 0x00164> in <34107616151548569c9b81c9b0f24a36#4e85f05b31daed62148693d6873ac2ea>:0 
2022-03-16 15:57:59.822677 +05:30   1   ERROR     at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc (System.DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone) <0x1046152e0 + 0x00027> in <34107616151548569c9b81c9b0f24a36#4e85f05b31daed62148693d6873ac2ea>:0 
2022-03-16 15:57:59.822677 +05:30   1   ERROR     at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (System.DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) <0x104614ef0 + 0x000e3> in <34107616151548569c9b81c9b0f24a36#4e85f05b31daed62148693d6873ac2ea>:0 
2022-03-16 15:57:59.822677 +05:30   1   ERROR     at System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (System.DateTime dateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone) <0x104614e50 + 0x00077> in <34107616151548569c9b81c9b0f24a36#4e85f05b31daed62148693d6873ac2ea>:0
```

Sometimes it throws this error can somebody help me out

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Kind property of dateTime is Utc but the sourceTimeZone does not equal TimeZoneInfo.Utc

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve] and give details of the platform you're running on. Here's an example that works for me: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/812d244bafd1c8453c7e7d491e376b60 - does that fail on your machine?

Comment: I don't think that's right. The overload `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone)` doesn't have a `sourceTimeZone` parameter. [This overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-6.0#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetime-system-timezoneinfo-system-timezoneinfo)) does, but that's not the one you said you're using

Comment: _"**Sometimes** it throws this error"_ - do you see any pattern in that "sometimes"? Like always between 8 and 12 P.M. ? Or something like that?

Comment: @Fildor yes I think so, I haven't noted the time frame pattern but I assume it might be because code is throwing error only sometime

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what your question says, the exception message and stack trace make it clear that you're calling [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-6.0#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetime-system-timezoneinfo-system-timezoneinfo)):

```
public static DateTime ConvertTime(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo sourceTimeZone,
    TimeZoneInfo destinationTimeZone);
```

If we look at the Remarks for that overload:

| DateTime.Kind value | sourceTimeZone value | Method behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `DateTimeKind.Utc` | Equals `TimeZoneInfo.Utc` | Converts `dateTime` to the destination time zone's time. |
| `DateTimeKind.Utc` | Does not equal `TimeZoneInfo.Utc` | Throws an `ArgumentException`. |
| `DateTimeKind.Local` | Equals `TimeZoneInfo.Local` | Converts `dateTime` to the destination time zone's time. |
| `DateTimeKind.Local` | Does not equal `TimeZoneInfo.Local` | Throws an `ArgumentException`. |
| `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` | Any. | Converts `dateTime` to the destination time zone's time. |

The second line is the problematic one. You're passing a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `DateTimeKind.Utc` (which is what you get from `DateTime.UtcNow`), but you're passing a `sourceTimeZone` which does not equal `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`, and so you're getting an `ArgumentException`.

Note how this overload is really only useful if your `Kind` is `Unspecified`. This makes sense: if the `Kind` is `Utc` or `Local`, `TimeZoneInfo` can work out what `sourceTimeZone` to use all by itself. If you insist on passing one, you need to make sure that you're passing the one which matches your `dateTime`. However if your `Kind` is `Unspecified`, then `TimeZoneInfo` doesn't know what time zone it's converting from, so you need to tell it.

Comment: Thanks alot understood, will do the change but I have a doubt that (TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime (DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local)) line works some time but throws error some times does it happens in certain time frame ? can you please explain this ?